# Pulling a substring and setting attributes. Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, nscolor

I have a string object that contains numerous color codes such as `ci=0,0,0` and `ci=0,25,225` I would like to take a substring between two color codes and change the color within that range. Does any one have a simple method to complete this task?

For example:

```
ci=0,0,0You are at a walkway.  
ci=0,0,0You are facing west. You see the ci=0,32,225creature controller roomci=0,0,0 to the ci=0,32,225northci=0,0,0
```

Each `ci=0,0,0`is the tag of a different color that should be displayed for the string immediately following.

I want to delete the ci color code and just display the text, but with the proper color.

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSString *testString= @"0,0,0You are at a walkway";
NSArray *array = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

you'll have:

```
array[0] = "0"
array[1] = "0"
array[2] = "0You are at a walkway"
```

If you also add a comma beween the "0" and the "You" in "...0You...", it will be easier, as you'll have:

```
array[0] = "0"
array[1] = "0"
array[2] = "0"
array[3] = "You are at a walkway"
```

Comment: ...And you still have a big problem regarding the "roomci=0,0,0 to", as there is no efective way to split the "room" from the "ci=...".
If you can add HTML like tag identifiers, it may simplify your life. You'd get something like:

<ci=0,0,0>You are facing west. You see the <ci=0,32,225>creature controller room<ci=0,0,0> to the <ci=0,32,225>north<ci=0,0,0>